# SubjectAltNames supported on IIS 5?

Tags: ssl, iis

I just generated a certificate with a CN and two subject alternative names (3 differents fqdn) and i always get a handshake failure, whatever the ssl version i use:

14177:error:1407F0E5:SSL routines:SSL2_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s2_pkt.c:428:
14176:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:530:

I'm now asking myself if IIS 5 on win2000 does really support those certificates, any ideas ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, IIS 5 does support SubjectAltNames. The handshake failure must be for another reason.